# Segmentation fault in Fortran while constructing graph using adjacency lists

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am creating graph using the adjacency list method. Each node is represented as a node which points to other nodes connected to it. The following is my  code

```
 program main
 use graphs
 implicit none
 type(node),pointer :: start
 type(node), dimension(:), pointer :: grp
 integer :: n, ios=0, a,b, i

 open(1, file='test6.txt', status='OLD', action='READ')
 read(1,*,iostat=ios) n
 allocate(start)
 allocate(grp(n))
 do, i=1,n
   grp(i)%val=i
 enddo

 do while(ios==0)
  read(1,*, iostat=ios)a,b
  if(ios.NE.0)then
     exit
  endif
  start => grp(a)
  call add(start, b)
  start => grp(b)
  call add(start, a)
 end do
end program main
```

The module graph is as follows

```
module graphs
 type node
  integer :: val
  type(node), pointer :: next
 end type node

contains

subroutine add(strt, nxn)
 implicit none
 type(node), pointer :: strt, new_node, lst
 integer :: nxn
 allocate(new_node)
 allocate(lst) 
 lst => strt
 new_node%val = nxn
 new_node%next => NULL()
 do while(associated(lst%next))
   lst => lst%next
 enddo
 lst%next => new_node
end subroutine add
end module graphs
```

File `test6.txt` is as follows

```
43
1 2
1 10
2 3
2 11
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
3 12
4 13
5 14
6 15
7 16
8 17
9 18
10 11
11 12
12 13
13 14
14 15
15 16
16 17
17 18
10 19
11 19
12 20
```

I am getting the following error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory
reference

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f786df6bef7 in ???
#1  0x7f786df6b12d in ???
#2  0x7f786dbbc4af in ???
#3  0x401db0 in __graphs_MOD_add
at /home/nav/MS project/new/grph.f90:18
#4  0x400f48 in ???
#5  0x400f85 in ???
#6  0x7f786dba782f in ???
#7  0x400a18 in ???
#8  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The above program is running smooth for small graphs but not working for large graphs. I am not able to get what am I doing wrong? I am using the gfortran compiler.

Comment: whats this for `allocate(l(n))` ? `l` doesn't appear to be declared or used anywhere.

Comment: Could you help us out by showing which line is `project/new/grph.f90:18`?

Comment: @agentp I was using this array previously. I forget to delete that.

Comment: @Brick 18th line is "do while(associated(lst%next))"

Comment: ok, you should edit the post to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code you set the starting `%next` pointer to null. So when you come to

```
do while(associated(lst%next))
```

the address where `lst%next` points to is undefined. You are not allowed to ask whether it is associated, because the result `associated()` will return is also undefined. See also this classical resource for some more explanation http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#5

The best cure is to the default initialization of pointer components

```
 type node
  integer :: val
  type(node), pointer :: next =>  null()
 end type node
```

Make it a habit to always set pointer components to null.