# Conditional fortran record variable selection

Tags: fortran

I have a structure defined:

```
STRUCTURE /IOA/
  INTEGER*2 ID
  .....
END STRUCTURE
```

I need to create another structure, IOB. IOB contains all the same fields as IOA but with many more.

```
STRUCTURE /IOB/
  INTEGER*2 ID
  .....
END STRUCTURE
```

My program currently has:

```
RECORD /IOA/ A
RECORD /IOB/ B
```

The program will either use A or B depending on a user input.

Is there any way to have some sort of conditional in the code to use A or B depending on what's required? For example, is it possible to create a placeholder record (variable?) "IO" and define it based on the input?:

```
If user input = 1, IO = A
else IO = B
.....

IO.ID = 30
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's Ada, not Fortran!

Comment: @Jack ... nope, that's a non-standard vendor extension to Fortran, made redundant by the 90 standard introduction of derived types.  If memory serves both gfortran and Intel Fortran will compile this type of code if treated nicely.

Comment: I understand derived (extended) types, but he wants a variable that can be of either type.  As far as I know, I cannot have a "supertype" pointer and point it to an object of the extended type.  Ada actually has "Types With Discriminants", in which parts of a object exist or do not exist depending on the value(s) of one (or more) of its members.

Comment: @Jack, do have something in mind distinct from polymorphism?

Comment: In Ada?  Yes.  Polymorphism is done with derived types, not types with discriminants.

Comment: Just a comment, you can create IOB using the "extends" command since it is IOA plus more.

Answer (score 3):

That's what polymorphism in modern Fortran (2003 and further) is for.

```
   use iso_fortran_env, only: int16

   implicit none

    type IOA
      integer(int16) :: ID
    end type


    type, extends(IOA) :: IOB
      integer :: extendedID
    end type

    class(IOA), allocatable :: IO

    integer :: user_input = 2

    if (user_input == 1) then
      allocate(IOA :: IO)
    else
      allocate(IOB :: IO)
    end if

    IO%ID = 30

    select type (IO)
      type is (IOB)
        IO%extendedID = 42
      class default !just an illustration
        continue
    end select
end
```

You can't do this with the obsolete DEC extensions STRUCTURE and RECORD. A advise against using these extensions. They are not part of standard Fortran.

Comment: I tried that, but the compiler (gfortran) would not let me use any attributes of the derived class, because the object pointer was defined to be of the parent class.

Comment: You must use `select type`.

Comment: I'd  very much appreciate it if you would update your example with an added attribute in IOB, and show how to set it right there at the end with `IO.ID = 30`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to make the type `IO_TYPE` in a module, and have it contain a POINTER to a type with the extra stuff you may or may not need:

```
MODULE IO_TYPES
  TYPE EXTRA_STUFF
     INTEGER :: AGE
     INTEGER :: HEIGHT
     INTEGER :: WIEGHT
  END type EXTRA_STUFF
  TYPE IO_TYPE
     INTEGER :: ID
     TYPE(EXTRA_STUFF), POINTER :: EXT
  END type IO_TYPE

END MODULE IO_TYPES
```

Then, in your program, which will have `USE IO_TYPES`, of course, you can decide whether to allocate that pointer:

```
TYPE (IO_TYPE) :: IO
INTEGER        :: IERR_ALLOC

IF ( USER_INPUT .EQ. 1 ) ALLOCATE( IO%EXT, STAT=IERR_ALLOC )
IF ( IERR_ALLOC .NE. 0 ) STOP 1
```

(Always check the results of ALLOCATE statements.)

Comment: I'd rather use an allocatable. Or, at least, nullify the pointer, to avoid mistakes like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399446/segmentation-fault-in-fortran-while-constructing-graph-using-adjacency-lists